# Best ubuntu server to use

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu-11.10

I'm installing ubuntu on my server instance, and I have the following distributions to choose from:

- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid)
- Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal)
- Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot)

Which of these is the best choice for me to go with?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not 12.04, the newest LTS?  Anyway, you question is junk.  How can we poosibly answer this in a useful way.  You have told us nothing about what you are doing.

Comment: The service provider may not offer it yet, e.g., Linode.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your requirements this is a silly question to answer. Any of those three will result in a running operating system. An LTS release will be supported with updates for longer so go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a server, I would definitely go for ubuntu 10.4. This is a lts: long term support version. It will receive security updates for a longer period of time:

[image: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ubuntu-release-cycle-2.png]

from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Apart from that it usually is more stable to start with, with a release date close to the debian stable releases.

Comment: In that case, why not go with 12.04, which is also a LTS release? The packages are much more up to date than 10.04. Unless you're worried about its newness of course, which is a valid point. Some people will decide to wait for 12.04.1, which is due in a few months.

Comment: @Martijn:  the question was which to choose from these 3. 12.04 would be a valid choice regarding support. Although I prefer an LTS which coincides with a freeze in debian.  Debian is where most testing occurs, not in ubuntu.[as a matter of fact, this is the reason that I choose debian squeeze for servers, not ubuntu]

Comment: You're right, of course. I wasn't aware of the sync with Debian releases. You have a good point about that. Personally I prefer Ubuntu LTS releases since the packages in Debian are often too old for my needs, and I try to avoid backports. However if you want stable, that's where it's at.

Answer (score 1):

First you never should prefer a non-LTS, especially one which is not the most recent.  So 11.04, should not even be a serious consideration.  There is exceptions, as always, but when speaking generally the recommendation holds.  This recommendation is only considering a server, a PC or workstation could use the regular releases.

I also would be hesitant to do an installation at this present moment, as the new LTS is already in BETA stage.  10.04, is not close to recent, although it does remain usable. If you are *OK* with running the older 10.04 software, with secuirty updates for 1.5 more years, it would suffice.

Truthfully *I* would get the most recent 12.04, and jump on early.  It's not the safe bet, but who wants to consider a reinstallation in a couple months.  However you might want to test it out, just to get a feel on how BETA it is currently.

Comment: I think Precise came out on Friday, actually.  Not all service providers have images yet, though.  OP should bug the service provider about when 12.04 images will be available, really.

Comment: This is true, but the OP did not specify if he was using a provider for his installation.  Regardless I voted up your answer, as it was basically solid advice.

Comment: BTW it's already out!!, I'm starting my installations now thanks for the update!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you're doing and what you're willing to put up with.  Note that 10.04 (and, recently released 12.04) are Long Term Support versions, which will ensure updates will be available for a very long time.  The 11.04 and 11.10 versions, not so much.

Basically, look at:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

So, 11.04 will be de-supported later this year, and 11.10 early next year.

If you don't care about the long term life of your server, 11.x would be fine (though, as said, 12.04 just came out, and will have shiny new things available also).  If you care about support, look at LTS versions.  If 10.04 is all you can use, bug your service provider on when they can provide 12.04.  If they can't provide 12.04 in a reasonable amount of time, and you want your support past the beginning of next year, use 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 must suit your needs if you are running the VPS to server websites. Ubuntu can utilise Nginx,varnish and all these tweaks.

Apart from this it is LTS and as many suggest, this version gets updates for a very long time.

I am a user of Linode and if you are on Linode, you already have the Option to rebuild with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

If you want the VPS for any applications or testing scripts, then make sure all the core components and sub components work and are supported on Ubuntu. Or else you can try something else like Cent OS or Archlinux.

Since no one here knows what you actually want, all we can do is suggest. It is upto you to make a choice and research on the available supported software on your project.